# header is not being set for a request of type get in axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt, get, http-headers

```
const config = {
          headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${auth?.accessToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          withCredentials: true,
        };
        
        const response = await axios.get(GRIEVANCE_URL, JSON.stringify({ user, pwd, grievCode }), config);
```

**Authorization header is not being set in the request headers**
Can anyone please explain me what went wrong in this?

> *Please note that all the backend is working fine as I tested it on thunder client. And also auth?.accessToken is defined and when logged in console, it was completely fine.*